# Box object over the sub report in rpt file gets cut off

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have designed a rpt file and have a sub report too. While drawing line over the sub report it gets cut off. How to solve this? below attached rpt file

[RPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuV01.png)

Comment: Please, post a snapshot of your designer.

Comment: @heringer attached  RPT file link

Comment: You mean the lines fully disappears as if the subreport is in front of them? Or you mean that they have gaps in the extremities?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the line(s) and select 'Move to Front'.  This will show the line over the subreport if they overlap.